# How can I align the placeholder in the input field to the top left?

Tags: html, css, input, frontend, placeholder

I want to align my placeholder to the upper left corner, but no matter what I tried, I couldn't do it. Unfortunately, other sources didn't help me either.

There is an answer to this question, but I couldn't find a source that does it without using `<div>`.

**Flexbox used.**

```
<div class="inputs">
     <input class="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
     <input class="mail" name="mail" type="text" placeholder="E-mail">
     <input class="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your message">
</div>
```

This is my css code. I tried to keep the placeholder in the upper **left corner**.

```
input[type=message]::placeholder {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: 0;
  }
```

Comment: The placeholder is supposed to give an example of what the input field is supposed to contain, so unless you would make the actual text the user types in display the same way, in the "upper left corner", this would IMHO rather be a misuse of placeholder in the first place. Placeholder is not a replacement for proper _labels_, and the values you have given those placeholders in your example _should_ actually be the labels of those fields.

Comment: an input is a single-line text input. It makes no sense to place a placeholder at the top-left. You might want to look into text-area (where you have a multi-line text input and the placeholder is at the top left by default in the LTR direction).

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can't position pseudo elements using the top, right, bottom, and left properties like you're trying to. Top left for a placeholder is definitely not possible (maybe I'm wrong),  but if you want to align the place holder to the left, center, or right, you can always use text align.

```
<!--HTML-->
<input class="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
```

```
/*css*/
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
text-align: center; 
}
```

I am assuming you want to have a large input field with the text at the top left corner. If so, the element you are looking for is not the `<input>` element but the Text area `<textarea></textarea>` element. This produces a large text field, and you do not have to position the placeholder. It is positioned at the top left by default. To shift the placeholder to the center or the right, you can just use the text align property.

Hope this helps!
Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

The best way to write message using . you dont have to set placeholder at top left in textarea element.

Comment: Typo-caused issues should not be answered but commented on and closed as `Not reproducible or caused by Typos`.  Missing reputation is no excuse to misuse the answer option to bypass your account limitations. Besides that, the issue is not typo-caused. Even the fix of a typo would not fix anything as the code can't work in that way for multiple reasons (replaced elements being one of them).

Comment: Thanks. for the correct me. I really don't  know about it

Answer (score -1):

When input have specified height, following code should work:

HTML:

```
 <input class="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
 <input class="mail" name="mail" type="text" placeholder="E-mail">
 <input class="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your message">
```

CSS:

```
input {
  height: 50px;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
  position:absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 20px; 
}
```